# Russian/Cyrillic alphabets under the simple commands in math modes - Latex

Tags: math-mode, cyrillic, alphabet

> Can we write the Russian/Cyrillic alphabets/symbols using the Latex under the math modes?

For example, for the Greek alphabet, like

> $\alpha$, $\beta$,

etc -- it is very easy. This is the sort of answer I want.

I am hoping to do the same for all these symbols below?
[image]

Comment: You can use `\textrm{}` or other commands that turn the text mode: $\textrm{русский текст}$.

Comment: nice thanks +1, let me try

Comment: at least, this does not work $\textrm{й}$ for me - it gives me an output "?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For UTF-8 encoding:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % for UTF8 codepage in Windows
\usepackage[russian]{babel}     % need for russian hyphenation and some typographic rules

\begin{document}
\[
    \textrm{текст на русском}
\]
\end{document}
```

For 1 byte codepage in Windows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}       % for 1-byte russian codepage in Windows
\usepackage[russian]{babel}         % need for russian hyphenation and some typographic rules

\begin{document}
\[
    \textrm{текст на русском}
\]
\end{document}
```

With obsolete package `mathtext` it is possible write in russian in math mode without any additional commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtext}               % must be before codepage and localization
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}       % for 1-byte russian codepage in Windows
\usepackage[russian]{babel}         % need for russian hyphenation and some typographic rules

\begin{document}
\[
    \alpha,\,\beta\quad текст\ на\ русском
\]
\end{document}
```

And russian letters by command in latin:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[OT1,T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\[
    \textrm{\cyrb\CYRB\cyrshch\cyryu\cyryo\cyrery\cyrie\cyry\cyrm\cyrya\cyrishrt\CYRISHRT}
\]
\end{document}
```

You can find full list of commands for russian (and other сyrillic) letters in this document: [The Cyrillic font encodings: T2A, T2B, T2C,and X2](http://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/required/cyrillic/cyoutenc.pdf).

Comment: thanks +1! is there a way not even to type русском/Russian, but still get Russian -- just like the Greek letter case?

Comment: `$$` shouldn't be used for maths in LaTeX. Can you use `\[ .. \]` instead?

Comment: @wonderich, for  single russian letters it is necessary to add inner LaTeX encoding `T2A`.

Comment: @cfr, OK, I fixed it.

Comment: This should be great \usepackage[OT1,T2A]{fontenc} - let me try.